# Grouping data outside limits in histogram using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, zooming, grouping, histogram

I am trying to do a histogram zoomed on part of the data. My problem is that I would like to grup everything that is outside the range into last category "10+". Is it possible to do it using ggplot2?

Sample code:

```
x <- data.frame(runif(10000, 0, 15))
ggplot(x, aes(runif.10000..0..15.)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y =  (..count..)/sum(..count..)), colour = "grey50", binwidth = 1) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0, 10)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 0:10)
```

Here is how the histogram looks now:
[How the histogram looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiPqd.png)

And here is how I would like it to look:
[How the histogram should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OT8Tu.png)

Probably it is possibile to do it by nesting ifelses, but as I have in my problem more cases is there a way for ggplot to do it?

Comment: The usual strategy with ggplot2 is to change the data if you want this type of change. So, for example, you can create a variable that has the category "10+", in which all the values in this bin and over are here. Plotting then is straightforward. (Also, "grupping"? You mean, "grouping"?)

Comment: oh! sorry for my spelling mistake!

Comment: no problem! I just wanted to make sure it wasn't something else :-)

Comment: Thank You. so I have done the following: 

1) assigned the categories:  
x$kat <- factor(ifelse(x$co_ile < 1  , "<0-1)", ... 
                levels = c("<0-1)", ....))

2) grouped results:  
z <- data.frame(prop.table(table(c$kat)))


3) create chart :   
ggplot(z, aes(x = Var1, y = Freq)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")

Bet there is a better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `forcats` and `dplyr` to efficiently categorize the values, aggregate the last "levels" and then compute the percentages before the plot. Something like this should work:

```
library(forcats)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

x <- data.frame(x = runif(10000, 0, 15))
x2 <- x %>%
  mutate(x_grp = cut(x, breaks = c(seq(0,15,1)))) %>% 
  mutate(x_grp = fct_collapse(x_grp, other = levels(x_grp)[10:15])) %>% 
  group_by(x_grp) %>% 
  dplyr::summarize(count = n())

ggplot(x2, aes(x = x_grp, y = count/10000)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", colour = "grey50") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)
```

However, the resulting graph is very different from your example, but I think it's correct, since we are building a uniform distribution:

[image]